# VPN-like solution for an office with no static public IP or port forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm part of a small business in an office block and have been racking my brains for a solution on how to get VPN access remotely to our LAN.

Our WAN internet access is provided by the office block and therefore we have no option for a public static IP or any port forwarding into our network.

We've got a DrayTek router which connects to the WAN and to our servers and a line to the office where we have a switch which connects our office PCs to the network.

Since there isn't a public IP and we cannot open ports in, I haven't been able to get a standard solution like OpenVPN to work.

I need a way to allow external computers, like our laptops to be able to connect to the LAN and access the private IPs and shared folders.

I'm rather stuck now and short of using something like LogMeIn Hamatchi (which I would prefer not to use) I am not entirely sure what option to pursue next - any help or pointers would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: If you do not have any information about some kind of external IP and options to use it you're going to have a hard time. Use a third party like a rented server that you connect to from the office and from your external devices would be an option. Pretty much what those ready to go VPN clients to.

Comment: [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: One question: Does your network have a own dynamic WAN ip address or is the WAN ip shared with other networks in your building?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, I will have a read of those now and see how they can help with a solution

Comment: @Seth a third party server is definitely an option. We are an AWS user for a lot of our work and so could easily put something on an EC2 instance or something. Do you have any further ideas as to what method to use?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring the public IP address we use is shared with other networks in the building

Comment: @EliotSmith you could use the EC2 as a openvpn server and you could configure your server in your network to automatically connect to the EC2 server and route incoming traffic into your network and outgoing to the openvpn interface.Now you would need to set up the EC2 server to also accept vpn connnections coming from your client and route the client's traffic into the interface of the vpn connection of your network-internal server and vice versa.